# fabric.IText to SVG produces TSPAN for each character

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How can I force the fabricjs IText object to produce a single text `<tspan>` when special formatting is not applied to the text?

When creating a new `fabric.IText()` object instance with an initial text value, the svg output is as expected.

For example:

```
    var textObject = new fabric.IText('{{variable2}}', {
        left: options.e.layerX,
        top: options.e.layerY,
        fontFamily: 'helvetica',
        fontSize: 10,
        angle: 0,
        fill: '#000000',
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        fontWeight: '',
        originX: 'left',
        hasRotatingPoint: true,
        centerTransform: true
    });

    canvas.add(textObject);
```

Produces the following output once `canvas.toSVG()` is called, which is what i'd expect.

```
<text font-family="helvetica" ...>
     <tspan x="-27" y="2.246" fill="#000000">{{variable2}}</tspan>
</text>
```

However, when you edit the IText text value, it produces a text object, with a tspan for each individual character.

Modifying the textObject's text inside the canvas editor to **"test {{variable2}}"**
Produces the following svg output:

```
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" font-family="helvetica" font-size="10" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #000000; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
    <tspan x="-37" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">t</tspan>
    <tspan x="-34" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">e</tspan>
    <tspan x="-28" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">s</tspan>
    <tspan x="-23" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">t</tspan>
    <tspan x="-20" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;"/>
    <tspan x="-17" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">{</tspan>
    <tspan x="-14" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">{</tspan>
    <tspan x="-11" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">v</tspan>
    <tspan x="-6" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">a</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">r</tspan>
    <tspan x="3" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">i</tspan>
    <tspan x="5" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">a</tspan>
    <tspan x="11" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">b</tspan>
    <tspan x="17" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">l</tspan>
    <tspan x="19" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">e</tspan>
    <tspan x="25" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">2</tspan>
    <tspan x="31" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">}</tspan>
    <tspan x="34" y="2.2459999999999996" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: #000000; fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">}</tspan>
</text>
```

**Edit**:  This behavior is still being experienced even if characters are inserted programatically.

```
$scope.addVariable = function() {
    var activeObject = $scope.getSelected();
    if (activeObject.isEditing) {
        activeObject.insertChars('{{name}}');
    }
};
```

**Edit**: I believe it has something to do with the copied styles being inserted when characters are inserted. See [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line22285)

Specifically: 
`activeObject.insertStyleObjects(_chars, isEndOfLine, activeObject.copiedStyles);`

Is there a way to insert characters without adding styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified the _setSVGTextLineChars in fabric.js to meet my needs.

The modified method groups all characters by styles.  If the current style is different than the previous style, a new grouping is defined.

For each group, a tspan is created with the related style.

i'm posting the code fragment below until someone else can provide an better answer.

```
    /**
     * @private
     */
    _setSVGTextLineChars: function (lineIndex, textSpans, height, textLeftOffset, textBgRects) {

        var chars = this._textLines[lineIndex].split(''),
            lineLeftOffset = this._getSVGLineLeftOffset(lineIndex) - this.width / 2,
            lineOffset = this._getSVGLineTopOffset(lineIndex),
            heightOfLine = this._getHeightOfLine(this.ctx, lineIndex);

        var previousStyleDecl = undefined;
        var groups = [];
        var currentGroup = undefined;

        for (var i = 0, len = chars.length; i < len; i++) {
            var styleDecl = this.styles[lineIndex][i] || {};

            var a = JSON.stringify(previousStyleDecl), b = JSON.stringify(styleDecl);
            if (!a) a = '';
            if (!b) b = '';
            var areEqualStyles = (a.split('').sort().join('') == b.split('').sort().join(''));

            var charWidth = this._getWidthOfChar(this.ctx, chars[i], lineIndex, i);

            // If the previous style is not defined,
            // or, the current style does not match the previous style, then
            // create a new grouping
            if (previousStyleDecl == undefined || !areEqualStyles) {

                var prevCharOffset = 0;

                if (currentGroup != undefined) {
                    prevCharOffset = currentGroup.charWidth;
                }

                currentGroup = {
                    style: styleDecl,
                    text: chars[i],
                    charWidth: charWidth,
                    charOffset: prevCharOffset
                }

                groups.push(currentGroup);
            }

            // if the styles are equal, then add the current character to the group
            if (areEqualStyles) {
                if (currentGroup) {
                    currentGroup.text += chars[i];
                    currentGroup.charWidth += charWidth;
                }
            } 

            previousStyleDecl = styleDecl;
        }

        var charOffset = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
            var group = groups[j];

            charOffset += group.charOffset;

            textSpans.push(this._createTextCharSpan(group.text, group.style, lineLeftOffset, lineOffset.lineTop + lineOffset.offset, charOffset));

            if (group.style.textBackgroundColor) {
                textBgRects.push(this._createTextCharBg(group.style, lineLeftOffset, lineOffset.lineTop, heightOfLine, group.charOffset, charOffset));
            }
        }
    },
```